# how to calculate time interval between to nonzero signal in python

Tags: python

I have two lists with the same length. The first list is time and the second one is a signal which has three values `0, 1, 2`. For example,

```
t = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0,
110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 140.0, 150.0, 160.0, 170.0, 180.0, 190.0, 200.0,
210.0, 220.0, 230.0, 240.0, 250.0, 260.0, 270.0, 280.0, 290.0, 300.0,
310.0, 320.0, 330.0, 340.0, 350.0, 360.0, 370.0, 380.0, 390.0]

s = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

The signal:

[image: signal]

I want to calculate the time interval when the signal is nonzero and when it is zero. The result should be

```
t_nonzero = [40, 10, 10, 10, ...]
t_zero = [20, 10, 40, 70, ...]
```

Is there an efficient way in python to do it?

Comment: My thinking is counting the number of nonzero elements in a sequence before it meets zero then multiply it by 10 to have `t_nonzero` and somehow similar for the `t_zero`. I'm trying to code it in python, which is my new friend.

Comment: @TienPhan If my answer solves your question you may click upvote &or accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be sufficient:

```
start = t[1]
sig = s[1]==0 # init signal
n = [] # non zero
z = [] # zero
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(t[1:],s[1:])):
    cur = y==0 # current signal
    # signal changes or meets the last frame
    if sig != cur or i == len(t[1:])-1:
        off = x - start
        z.append(off) if sig else n.append(off)
        start = x
        sig = cur
```

Notice the first frame is discarded.

---

**Update:** Another solution is counting the signals.

```
def fn(n):
    n[-1] += 1

n = [0] # non-zero
[fn(n) if x != 0 else n.append(0) for x in s[1:]] # discard the first frame
n = [x * 10 for x in n if x > 0]

z = [0] # zeros list
[fn(z) if x == 0 else z.append(0) for x in s[1:]]
z = [x * 10 for x in z if x > 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works pretty well except for not giving the last interval in `t_nonzero`. I'm checking.

Comment: @TienPhan Added a check for the last frame. Not sure how you count the last interval's durance.

Comment: If we look at the last interval's durance in the graph, it starts nonzero at 290 and ends at 390, so the last element in `n` should be 100 instead of 90 as in your answer.

Comment: Discarding the first frame, if we take 10 multiple by the number of elements in the nonzero sequence in the `signal` list, it should give the interval for `n` and the number of elements in  zero sequence for `z`. I haven't figured out a way to do it in python.

Comment: @TienPhan Just add 10 to the last frame. And the second solution should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I hope this helps.

this is a function you can use to plug in your two lists

```
def btwn(t,s):
    t_zero = []
    t_non_zero = []
    running = 0
    if s[0]==0: #Assign the starting value
        prev_zero = True
    else:
        prev_zero = False
    for score in range(len(s)): #run the length of the lists, using the position
        #compare current score to previous score
        #if the previous and current are same, keep a running
        #total of the difference, if they change, dump that 
        #running total into the appropriate list
        if score != 0: #unless it's the first element, add to running 
            running += t[score] - t[score - 1]
        if (s[score] == 0 and prev_zero) or (s[score] != 0 and not prev_zero): 
        #unchanged, add to running
            continue    
        elif s[score] == 0: #changed to zero from non-zero
            prev_zero = True
            t_non_zero.append(running)
            running = 0
        else: #changed to non-zero from zero
            prev_zero = False
            t_zero.append(running)
            running = 0
    if prev_zero: #add the final value to one of the two lists
        t_zero.append(running)
    else:
        t_non_zero.append(running)
    return t_zero, t_non_zero #return the lists
```

This function will accept 2 lists, and return 2 lists.

The function starts with a running calculated number at zero, reads the first list value from s to decide if we're starting at zero or not then looks at each value in the list sequentially.
It adds the running total up at each iteration depending on the time in t between this element and the previous one. If the value switches for zero to non-zero or vice versa, it dumps the running total to the appropriate list and resets the running total.

I tested it and this function returned the lists you desired, although the first element of non-zero is actually 50, not 40. The value for s is non_zero for the first 5 consecutive periods of 10 seconds, and it is not until the sixth element that it changes to zero. Even though the first element is at time = 0, it is still non_zero value for each space between elements until you collect the next score change at element 6.

you can call the function and then assign it to those desired output lists if you wish

```
#example 
t_zero, t_non_zero = btwn(t,s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and beautiful explanation. We measured the signal, it was initially nonzero and dropped to zero at t = 40 as in the graph, so we take the first nonzero interval as 40. We can discard the first frame for clarity and your answer works but it doesn't return the last value 100 in `t_non_zero`. The expected `t_non_zero = [40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100]`.

Comment: I see what you are saying when looking at the graph. You may want to adjust the list in that case if s = 0 at t = 40.0. The function does return 90 as the closing value for the 2 lists. If you expect 100, then you will need a data point that matches your graph for s = 2 at t = 400.0. I appended the value to the lists and changed s to 0 at t = 40 and got the expected results. If you cannot change the lists then the function would have to change.